# Binary Division using Templated Big Integers

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a Division Binary Algorithm.

The code has some Logical Errors which I am still trying to figure out how to fix them.

```
myuint operator/(const myuint<T>& x)
    {
        myuint<T> temp;
        myuint<T> result;

        int count = 0;

        for(int i = bits.size() - 1 ; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            temp.bits.push_back(bits[i]);

            if(temp >= x)
            {
                count++;
                *this = *this - x;
                temp = 0;
            }    
        }

        result = count;

        return result;
   }
```

I am also overloading the >=, >, and == operators for the division.

The logical problem most probably is in the for loop . What should I do? Thanks

Full code can be accessible from [here](https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/c-iLChhy)

== EDIT

What I am trying to achieve is this.
*this is 10100 (20 in decimal)
x is 100 (4 in decimal)

1. Get the first Bit (1).
2. Compare it to x
3. If the bit is greater than the value of x, count++, subtract x from *this. And then Start the loop again which a different *this size.
4. If the bit is small, then we move to the bit next to it so, now we have 2 bits (10) and we compare it to x.
5. Then I return the value of count which represents this number of divisions to reach 0.

Comment: Where does `bits` come from?

Comment: bits is a bool<vector>

Comment: All of your errors come from using `int` instead of `size_t` in your loops; `size()` methods usually return a `size_t`: https://godbolt.org/z/MPo6nedb8

Comment: Two things: Your question needs a [mcve], along with expected and actual behaviour. Secondly, get into "test-driven development".

Comment: *The code has some Logical Errors which I am still trying to figure out how to fix them.* -- You fix the errors by taking a step back from the code, getting a pencil and paper, and working out the logic using pencil and paper.  Once you have the logic worked out using pencil and paper, go back to the code and implement that logic.  Then you will either discover that you implemented your logic incorrectly and thus you will simply need to fix the bugs so that your logic is correctly implemented, or you discover that your pencil/paper logic is flawed and you need to start over.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but here is the algorithm that you need to implement:

```
myuint div(const myuint& x, const myuint& y)
{
    if (y == 0)
        throw "division by zero";

    myuint res = 0;
    myuint one = 1;

    unsigned int xLength = x.bitLength();
    unsigned int yLength = y.bitLength();

    while (xLength > yLength)
    {
        res += one << (xLength - yLength - 1);
        x -= y << (xLength - yLength - 1);
        xLength = x.bitLength();
    }

    if (x >= y)
        return res+1;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a simple implementation of how to go around Binary Division.

The idea is that you subtract the LSH from the RHS until LHS is smaller RHS and keep a hold for the many times you subtracted RHS from LSH.

```
myuint operator/(const myuint<T>& x)
{

    myuint<T> LHS = *this;
    myuint<T> RHS = x;
    myuint<T> result;

    int count = 0;
    bool flag = true;
    
    if(LHS == RHS)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if(LHS >= RHS)
            {
                LHS = LHS - RHS;
                count++;
            }
            else if(LHS < RHS)
            {
                flag = false;
            }   
        }while(flag);
            
    }

    result = count;

    return result;
}
```

This may not be the most efficient way. But it gets the job done.

Comment: "not the most efficient" is an understatement. The runtime complexity of this algorithm is `O(2^N)`, where `N` is the number of bits in the input. Even for a "standard" 32-bit integer, this would execute around 4 billion iterations. And the objective of this dude is presumably to implement a big-number class, meaning, a much larger (possibly unlimited-size) integer.

Comment: What are your recommendations ?

Comment: Long division, where the runtime complexity is `O(N)`.

Comment: Oh, I just realized that you're the same dude who asked this question in the first place. So my suggestion is in the answer that I gave you yesterday. Have you had a look at it? You'd need to implement some additional functionality in your `myuint` class, like `operator<<(unsigned int)` and `bitLength()`, as well as the standard comparison operators (`<=`, etc). But it should be fairly simple once you've achieved that.